# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map when using jdbc8.jar and Oracle client 18

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g

I have a java app that extracts large xml from an Oracle 11g database Release 11.2.0.4.0 (using spring 4) and stores them in files. We had a problem extracting data containing multibyte characters. Depending on where in the xml the multibyte was it would sometimes split the multibyte into 2 parts. It looked like the problem was to do with the version of jdbc and the oracle client installed. So we migrated to Oracle client 18 and ojdb8.jar, leaving the code untouched. The multibyte problem was solved, but now instead we have memory issues that were not happening before. The error I get is:

## There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.

## Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 256376832 bytes for committing reserved memory.

I have played around with the java command parameters but to no avail. This is  what I am running:
    java -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -Doracle.jdbc.timezoneAsRegion=false -Xmx10240m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/tmp -XX:NativeMemoryTracking=detail -XX:+StartAttachListener -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintNMTStatistics

Decreasing Xmx to 512m ended up with running out of heap memory.

I have monitored the application's memory using jcmd  VM.native_memory baseline/summary.diff and GC.class_stats and one of the biggest memory consumers are String objects. I was not able to make sense of the rest.

the sql is: 
    SELECT XML_DATA
FROM  table where....

The xml_data column is defined as:
XML_DATA   NOT NULL SYS.XMLTYPE STORAGE BINARY

mapping this in java to oracle.xdb.XMLType:

```
public List<XMLType> extractXmlDataList(String sqlExtractionQuery, Key key) {
    MapSqlParameterSource namedSqlParams = createKeyParamMap(key);
    List<XMLType> dataList = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForList(sqlExtractionQuery, namedSqlParams, XMLType.class);
    return dataList;
}


protected void extractXmlData(Key key) {
List<XMLType> xmlRecs = producerDao.extractXmlDataList(sqlExtractionQuery, patentKey);
    if (xmlRecs != null && xmlRecs.size() > 0) {
        for (XMLType xmlData : xmlRecs) {
            String xmlText = xmlData.getStringVal();
            //create nu.xom.Document
            Builder parser = new Builder();
            Document xmlDocument = parser.build(xmlText, null);
        }
    }       
}
```

How can moving to Oracle client 18 and jdbc8.jar have affected the memory consumption so much?

Comment: Why do you load 250MB directly into memory? I suggest using `InputStream`

Comment: Not sure I understand why that would help. In the end I would have to convert the InputStream into a String to create the XML Document, no?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do with the XML, you almost never have to read a whole file into memory.

Comment: In this case I have to read the whole data into memory, can't see any other way.

Comment: (Wild guess because I'm not familiar with Java) Is there some default prefetch size with the new client?  Maybe the client is trying to read too many rows at once, and the large XML column results are consuming all the memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The memory issue was solved by using xmlserialize rather than Oracle Java XMLType object. Still using Oracle client 18 and ojdbc8.jar. No further problems with multibyte UTF8 splitting.